# print specific part of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to print part of an array where a number is given as the end of that array.
It's hard to explain with words so let me get straight to the point.
Let's say I have an array {1,...,6,...,9}. I want to return elements only from 1 to 6.
These numbers are not the indexes they are the actual values.

Example input:

- arr= {1,2,3,11,6,8,12}
- function : cut(arr, 6)
- output: {1,2,3,11,6}.

Of course, if the number given as an argument is not in arr it will return an error.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,11,6,8,12};
        int value = 6;
        
        System.out.println("Input: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

        // primitive way
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            if (arr[i] == value) {
                System.out.print("Now stop");
                break;
            }
        }

        // What I need:
        arr = cut(arr, 6);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static int[] cut(int[] arr, int value) {
        // Best way in Java to reduce the array?

        return arr;
    }
}
```

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 11, 6, 8, 12]
1 2 3 11 6 Now stop
Output: [1, 2, 3, 11, 6, 8, 12] <- should be [1, 2, 3, 11, 6]
```

Comment: So what have you tried?  We can help diagnose problems in code. We don't write the code for you.

Comment: If you expect us to put in effort to produce quality Answers,  you should put in the effort to write a quality Question, drafting a clear concise problem description. Your current draft seems a bit lazy. Certainly it is unclear.

Comment: The answer to your revised question is: look at the javadocs for `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine the position of your value in the array.
Then you can take the subarray from the start index to that position.
Plus one to include the searched value.

Unfortunately, there is no `indexOf` method for arrays and `Arrays.binarySearch` works only on sorted arrays. There is no `Arrays.search` either.

Therefore, we need either transform the array into a list to use `indexOf` or we need to iterate the array via index until we find the search value.

There is no `List<int>`. Therefore we need to transform the elements from `int` to `Integer`. Hence, the `boxed` operation.

In the end, using a list is not worth it but it is a fun exercise!

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,11,6,8,12};
        int value = 6;
        
        System.out.println("Input:  " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        arr = cut(arr, 6);
        System.out.println("Output: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }

    public static int[] cut(int[] arr, int value) {
        int position = Arrays.stream(arr) // turn into stream
                        .boxed() // turn elements into class Integer 
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()) // turn into list
                        .indexOf(value); // find position with list operation
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, position + 1);
    }
}
```

Et voilà:

```
Input:  [1, 2, 3, 11, 6, 8, 12]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 11, 6]
```